# How to compare two voices in Android?

Tags: android, audio, recording, speech

I want to compare two voices(Names) in my App. Can I use Speech to Text api for it? The idea is to first convert them to text and then compare. Has anybody have tried it? If yes how accurate is it?

Comment: how exactly do you compare *voices* if you speech-to-text them first?

Comment: probably you should go through Fourier

Comment: Idea is to convert the short voice like a single spoken word to text using speech to text api and store it in memory as reference as TextA. Later the spoken words are converted to text and compared against the saved reference textA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing two audio files for similarity is an imperfect science best approached with hammers like Fast Fourier Transforms, audio "fingerprinting", and heuristic analysis. You will need to  read up on signal analysis to get started. I recommend starting with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705224/matching-two-audio-files) to get some ideas.