# In android is there a way to compare two audio files for similarity between them?

Tags: android

I am currently working on a game that requires me to record an audio file,which is made up of a text read by a person. This particular audio file needs to be compared with another (default) audio file, for the recording of which same text as before was used (while creating the game). Now I need to know how similar these two files are. Is there a way to do that? A function that returns me a similarity index? Even if I have to integrate an external library, its fine.

I have read online about using FFT and correlation methods to do that, but is there a library that has all those techniques already built in it?

Comment: I found a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705224/matching-two-audio-files. May be this will help you and see this one also http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/01/compare-two-sounds-in-android.html

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653466/simplest-algorithm-of-measuring-how-similar-of-two-short-audio

Answer (score 0):

Yes, te base of this library should be **FFT** (fast Fourier transform) for taking all mixing of every single frequence of your files. It means, by a short way, 'transform audio into frequences (number) by time axis'.
But when someone is reading, there can be a diferent ways to make it with different frequences. The differentiation of voice is not frecuences, is **modulation**. Then, you will need harder FFT library. Maybe with 'Speech-Recognition' (witch includes FFT modulation) you will be able to make it possible.

Best reguards