# Compare two audios if match then immediately mute the system in android

Tags: android

I want to compare two audio files one file is already store in app and the other file is detect by background sound of user's phone like: music or FM and compare both files if the word which store in first audio is matched with background song's lyrics then it will immediately mute the system. I don't understand how can i detect the lyrics and compare both file.

How could i do that comparison in order to get a match? What is the process to follow in this type of apps?

If anyone have answer of my question and relevant code also then please share with me

Comment: downvoters please do not downvote without posting solution/reason, please be little patient with newbies

Comment: what have you done so far ? please post the code.

Comment: You may find some relevant info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705224/matching-two-audio-files?rq=1